# Some PUBG API returning 404

Tags: json, api, get

***Some PUBG API endpoints are returning 404 with the message "Player Not Found"***

I've checked that my API key is working properly because I can successfully query other endpoints.

I'm using postman to submit a GET request to the following address:

`https://api.pubg.com/shards/steam/players/13DEMAH`

I have the following two items included in my header:

```
Authorization: Bearer myApiKey
accept: application/vnd.api+json
```

A link to the PUBG documentation: [PUBG Documentation](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/players-endpoint.html#/Players/get_players__accountId_)

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong it would be really helpful because I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are using this endpoint `/players/{accountId}` which require the internal ID in the PUBG API.

So what you can use is:

`https://api.pubg.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=13DEMAH`

To get the information about a PUBG username. (you can also use this endpoint to fetch up to 10 players stats)